# NHibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: -1;

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, nhibernate

Suddenly all of update queries on NHibernate running against SQL Server started returninig the exception `NHibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: -1;`

Suspecting some change in the db server itself caused this, not sure what.

Comment: I can't speak to nhibernate but rowcount -1 is returned by most client APIs when the query is run with the `SET NOCOUNT ON` session setting. Perhaps there was a configuration or stored procedure change that chaned the setting from the default `SET NOCOUNT OFF` to `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman - this got me onto the right path.

Answer (score 1):

It was a server setting after all - someone set the user options NOCOUNT flag which prevented NHibernate to report row counts:

To fix the issue I had to set the value from (notice the tenth bit from the right side):

0111 0111 1000 = 1912

To:

0101 0111 1000 = 1400

```
EXEC sp_configure 'user options', 1400;
GO  
RECONFIGURE;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-options-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: I see in someone set the NOCOUNT option at the server level. Personally, I would avoid that and do it only at the session or proc level when required. Same with other user options.